# Import methods that select the features in Weka

Tags: python-3.x, weka

I am a beginner on using Weka. I computed the features by Python code and filled the results in excel sheet. My data to be evaluated are texts. Example of features I used, average word length, the percentage of letters, complexity ...etc.

my question is: can I enter the text segments in Weka and it computes all those features by importing my method for each feature? 
if yes how that will be done?

or the data should be evaluated before then the results insert into weka as arff file.

I did not find the answer to my question while searching.